# DRF - How to generate nested json with serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm a beginer in DRF and here is a simple illustration of the nested json I want to generate:

```json
{
  "shop_name": "some_text",
  "shop_intro": "some_text",
  "swiper_images": [
    {
      "id": "id_num",
      "swiper_image": "some_url",
      "swiper_image_alt": "some_text"
    },
    {
      "id": "id_num",
      "swiper_image": "some_url",
      "swiper_image_alt": "some_text"
    },
    {
      "id": "id_num",
      "swiper_image": "some_url",
      "swiper_image_alt": "some_text"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my `models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models


class ShopIndexPage(models.Model):
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="Shop Name")
    intro_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="Intro Text")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Shop text of " + self.shop_name


class SwiperImage(models.Model):
    swiper_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/index/swiper-images', default="None")
    swiper_image_alt = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.swiper_image_alt
```

Here is my `serializer.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ShopIndexPage, SwiperImage


class SwiperImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SwiperImage
        fields = ['swiper_image', 'swiper_image_alt']


class ShopIndexPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    swiper_items = SwiperImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ShopIndexPage
        fields = ['id', 'shop_name', 'intro_text', 'swiper_items']
```

Here is my `views.py`:

```py
from .models import ShopIndexPage
from .serializers import ShopIndexPageSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def index_list(request, format=None):
    if request.method == "GET":
        index_queryset = ShopIndexPage.objects.all()
        serializer = ShopIndexPageSerializer(index_queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == "POST":
        serializer = ShopIndexPageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I got the following error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
> swiper_items on serializer ShopIndexPageSerializer`. The serializer
> field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on
> the ShopIndexPage instance.

Original exception text was: `ShopIndexPage object has no attribute swiper_items.`

---

I've been reading several posts and tried their fix, but none is working for me, here are some of them:

#1

```py
class ShopIndexPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    swiper_items = SwiperImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ShopIndexPage
        # fields = ['id', 'shop_name', 'intro_text', 'swiper_items']
        fields = '__all__'
```

I got the same error.

#2

```py
class ShopIndexPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # swiper_items = SwiperImageSerializer(many=True)
    swiper_items = SwiperImageSerializer(many=True, source='*')

    class Meta:
        model = ShopIndexPage
        fields = ['id', 'shop_name', 'intro_text', 'swiper_items']
```

Now the error became: 'ShopIndexPage' object is not iterable

Comment: You either have to add db relation between your models or property named swiper_images on your ShopIndexPage returning queryset of SwiperImage

Comment: @PTomasz Could you provide some example code or a tutorial link? Thanks.

Comment: Posted it as answer due to code formatting, but @May.D posted really nice answer using different approach

Answer (score 1):

You should change your SwiperImage to that (on the assumption that SwiperImage can be assigned to single ShopIndexPage):

```
class SwiperImage(models.Model):
    shop_index_page = models.ForeignKey(to=ShopIndexPage, related_name='swiper_images')
    swiper_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/index/swiper-images', default="None")
    swiper_image_alt = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.swiper_image_alt
```

and then in your serializer you can:

```
class ShopIndexPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    swiper_items = SwiperImageSerializer(many=True, source='swiper_images')

    class Meta:
        model = ShopIndexPage
        fields = ['id', 'shop_name', 'intro_text', 'swiper_items']
```

If you have migrations you will have to revert them, delete migration files of this app and then run makemigrations and migrate again

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import models


class SwiperImage(models.Model):
    swiper_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/index/swiper-images', default="None")
    swiper_image_alt = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.swiper_image_alt


class ShopIndexPage(models.Model):
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="Shop Name")
    intro_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="Intro Text")
    swiper_images = models.ManyToManyField(SwiperImage, related_names='swiper_image')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Shop text of " + self.shop_name
```

These models schema will generate expected json response as you want

Note: Do other stuff in `serializers.py` or `views.py` file

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between your two models, this is why you get this error message `ShopIndexPage object has no attribute swiper_items`. You could add a db relation as suggested by @PTomasz but to me it won't make much sense to define a foreign key between `Item` and `ShopPage`.

I suggest that you use a `SerializerMethodField` instead.

```
class ShopIndexPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    swiper_items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ShopIndexPage
        fields = ['id', 'shop_name', 'intro_text', 'swiper_items']
    
    def get_swiper_items(self, page):
        items = SwiperImage.objects.all()
        return SwiperImageSerializer(items, many=True).data
```

Comment: Can't edit due to less than 10 chars, but you wrote items = SwiperImageSerializer.objects.all() instead of items = SwiperImage.objects.all()